# Password replication across AD sites

Tags: active-directory, password

We are going to be adding a few new Domain Controllers into our school environment to have authentication closer to the end user.  I've read about creating the site links and setting the replication intervals there, but I was just trying to get some clarification on how passwords work.

If all DCs are set to replicate from the main DC at SITEA, and someone at SITEB needs a password reset, do I need to reset their password from the DC at SITEB?  Or will resetting the password on the DC at SITEA automatically push it down to the other DCs, or does it have to wait for the next tick of the replication interval?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The password is replicated to the domain controller with the PDC Emulator role immediately, at the next replication interval to all other domain controllers.

Additionally, if a logon fails, the authentication is attempted at the the PDC Emulator role domain controller, so you should not need to be too concerned about the effects of delayed replication for password changes.

Comment: In addition to Greg's answer, I'll add this: your statement `I've read about creating the site links and setting the replication intervals there` gives me pause. If you don't have a specific reason for manually managing the replication topology then don't. Let the KCC and ISTG do their jobs. (The KCC is responsible for generating the intra-site replication topology and the ISTG is responsible for generating the inter-site replication topology).

Comment: Sorry i'm a little confused, these schools don't have domain controllers now they just have DHCP servers.  When adding a DC to a remote site aren't you supposed to create the site in Sites and Services, assign the DC to that site, then configure the site link / replication frequency?

Comment: So the password will replicate from a remote DC to the PDC if a password is changed, but is the opposite true?  We manage the passwords here, so if someone needs a password changed at another building with it's own DC, do I need to perform the reset there?  Or can I reset everything from the PDC?

Comment: You don't need to specify the domain controller when resetting the password.

Comment: Yes, you should create the Sites and Subnets and assign the appropriate DC's to the appropriate Sites, but you do not need to manually create the replication topology. The Intersite Topology Generator will do that automatically. In probably 99% of AD deployments, no manual intervention is needed or required.

Comment: You're over thinking things a little bit. When you need to change a password for a user or when a user needs to change their own password, you can change it on any DC or the user can use the normal password change mechanism and AD will take care of the rest. I hate to over simplify things too much, but for the most part, in a well designed and implemented AD, AD is  largely "set it and forget it".

Comment: Ok great, I was hoping that was the case, I just wasn't sure if the password change got pushed automatically or not, or if it had to wait for replication.  So if I changed a pw on DC1, but the user authenticates to DC2, I wasn't sure if it would reflect the new password until replication had occured.  Thanks for the help.